# Pagination query using SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called 'items'

It has the following columns: `id`, `name`, `stock`, `price`, and `category_id`.

My query is

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE category_id = {$category_id} LIMIT 10;
```

my logic for next page is store all ids in a variable called `$oldIds` and the next query is:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE category_id = {$category_id} AND id NOT IN ($oldIds)  LIMIT 10
```

for another page is i store again the ids from 1st page and 2nd page  do again the query

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE category_id = {$category_id} AND id NOT IN ($oldIds)  LIMIT 10
```

Do i continue using this style of query or is there a better way of querying?

Comment: i only forgot to inlude the limit 10 so i edit the question

Comment: Instead of doing it like this, why not order the products by name/id/stock/price and use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`

Comment: oh thanks @ScottMcGready

Comment: i did not know how to use offset until i read your comment and search for this

Comment: @ScottMcGready your a life saver thanks bro i hope you the answer instead of comment. i will accept at the answer below because it it gave also the right answer this comment is to appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### for mysql

First statement should be:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} ORDER BY datetime ASC LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {offset}
```

if 10 records per page is what you are looking for and you want to show records on page 2 i.e. records 11-20 your query will look like:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} ORDER BY datetime ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```